# UIAlertView exec_bad_access form block object

Tags: xcode, uialertview, objective-c-blocks

I am getting an EXEC_BAD_ACCESS when I try to display a UIAlertView within a block object. If I call the "onEventAdded" method from the "viewDidAppear" method the alert works as expected.

Thanks in advance.

```
- (void) addEvent:(NSDictionary *) event_data
{
   NSLog(@"event_data: %@ ",event_data);    
   // create event
   EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

   [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {

        // event code ...

        NSError *err;
        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
        if(err == NULL)
        {
            [self onEventAdded];
        }
    }];
}

-(void) onEventAdded{
   uiAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: nil
                                               message: @"Event added to calendar."
                                              delegate: nil
                                     cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                     otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
   [uiAlert show];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The completion block is probably not executed on the main thread. You can only do UI stuff (e.g. showing alert) on the main thread.

Comment: That did the trick. I added [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(onEventAdded) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; at the end of the block object and it works. Thanks